# comma seperated list of attributes of model's attribute from backbone

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections, backbone-model

I have backbone collection with several models. I want comma separated string of one attribute of that models exist in this collection. How do I do this? any guess? 
later on I want filter this collection with specific attribute and then get comma separated string.

example : 
var collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({ 
        url:'/getsuggestions',
        model: SomeModel
    })
1st model in collection has value like this :
SomeModel.set('attr1', '1');
SomeModel.set('attr2', '2');
SomeModel.set('attr3', '3');

2nd model in collection has value like this :
SomeModel.set('attr1', '101');
SomeModel.set('attr2', '202');
SomeModel.set('attr3', '303');

above both model exist in collection. Now I want 'attr1' as comma separated string like '1,101'.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the collection [pluck method](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-pluck)\

[here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/6Dz62/) using :

```
collection.pluck('attr1').toString()
```